Get Hands-On with an Iterable Variable in For Loops
I am unable to complete this Trailhead Module: [Get Hands-On with an Iterable Variable in For Loops][1], because I keep getting this error message:
"The constructor MyIterable should accept parameter of type List<String>."
Here's my MyIterable Class with its constructor accepting the correct type of parameter:
public class MyIterable implements Iterable<String> {
    
    private List<String> strings;
    
    public MyIterable(List<String> strList) {
        strings = strList;
        strings.iterator();
    }
    
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
      return strings.iterator();
   }
}
´´´

[1]: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/platform-developer-i-certification-maintenance-winter-25/get-hands-on-with-iterable-variable-in-for-loops?trail_id=maintain-your-salesforce-certifications


try public MyIterable(List<String> strings) as per the instructions

Try this one for the constructor and below sample code it should work:
public class MyIterable implements Iterable<String> {
    private List<String> strings;

    public MyIterable(List<String> strings) {
        this.strings = strings;
    }

    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return strings.iterator();
    }
}

In case you need Test Class:
@IsTest
public class MyIterableTest {
    @IsTest
    static void testIterableForLoop() {
        List<String> strings = new List<String>{'Hello', 'World'};

        MyIterable iterable = new MyIterable(strings);

        for (String str : iterable) {
            System.debug(str);
        }
    }
}


This happened with me, and it ultimately turned out to be that I had "MyIterable (" instead of "MyIterable(". The name of the variable mattered as well, anything other than "strings" will cause this error to occur. It also fails for another error is you use "return this.strings.iterator();" in the iterator method.
I feel like the challenge checker used to be smarter than it is today.
